# Make @intrinsic return a tuple

Tags: python, numpy, llvm, numba

I'm trying to implement a `(uint64 a)*(uint64 b)->(uint64 higher,uint64 lower)` function in numba. This was what I got fighting all night. There are really few examples online about this:

```
import numpy as np
from llvmlite import ir
from numba import njit, types
from numba.extending import intrinsic

@intrinsic
def mul_(ctx, a, b):
    def gen(ctx, build: ir.IRBuilder, sig, a):
        u8 = ir.IntType(64)
        u16 = ir.IntType(128)
        a = build.mul(build.zext(a[0], u16), build.zext(a[1], u16))
        # return build.addrspacecast(a, ctx.get_value_type(sig.return_type))
        o = build.alloca(u8, 2)
        O = build.bitcast(o, ir.ArrayType(u8, 2))
        build.store(build.trunc(build.lshr(a, u16(64)), u8), build.gep(o, [u8(0)]))
        build.store(build.trunc(a, u8), build.gep(o, [u8(1)]))
        return o

    return types.Tuple((types.u8, types.u8))(types.u8, types.u8), gen


@njit
def mul(x, y):
    mul_(x, y)


a = 2**63 - 1
t = mul(a, a)
```

I found no matter what I do, it either says `Can't index at [0] in i64*` (for lower case `o`), or `'ArrayType' object has no attribute 'pointee'` (for upper case `O`). Can any one tell me what's the proper way of doing this?

It would even be better to directly return int128. Maybe as `S16`, `V16` or etc? I tried casting `int128` directly to `[int64 x 2]`, but it says it can't cast this way. As long as it's returned to outside python world, I can always `np.view` it to anything I want.

Answer (score 1):

After another few hours of endless trying, I finally start to understood how to use this whole `llvmlite` system.

Essentially I need to `allocate a pointer (i.e. array of size 1) of a structure of {int32,int32}` instead of `allocate an array (of size 2) of int32`, which kind of make sense I guess? This is a working one:

```py
@intrinsic
def mul_(ctx, a, b):
    def gen(ctx, build: ir.IRBuilder, sig, a):
        u8 = ir.IntType(64)
        u16 = ir.IntType(128)
        a = build.mul(build.zext(a[0], u16), build.zext(a[1], u16))
        o = build.alloca(ir.ArrayType(u8, 2))
        build.store(build.trunc(build.lshr(a, u16(64)), u8), build.gep(o, [u8(0), u8(0)]))
        build.store(build.trunc(a, u8), build.gep(o, [u8(0), u8(1)]))
        return build.load(o)

    return types.Tuple((types.u8, types.u8))(types.u8, types.u8), gen


@njit
def mul(x, y):
    return mul_(x, y)


a = 2**63 - 1
mul(a, a)
```

But I still fell this is kind of dump to do all kinds of `shift`+`trunc`+`alloc`+`pointer stuff`. Can't I just "view" this `int128` into `[int64 x 2]`? Is there any more elegant answer?

Answer (score 0):

LLVM is not C; it doesn't have the pointers-and-array confusion that originates in C's transformation from BCPL. In LLVM, if you want an array, you need an array type and nothing else.

LLVM also doesn't permit you to assume much about the target CPU. For example, it doesn't permit you to assume that the CPU will have instructions that operate on half-registers, or quarter-registers, or any such thing. You may assume that it has registers, but if you want to see what a part of a register is, you have to do the shifting and masking yourself. This is the reason that you can't just bitcast.

And LLVM doesn't permit you to assume that arrays are unpadded: An array of two x-bit integers may occupy more than 2x bits, the backend decides that and you don't.

I think with all this, the sources of your problems should be clear.

The solution isn't too involved. You'll need one multiplication (NUWMul IIRC, but it's been a while), after that one right shift and two truncs to create the two 64-bit values, then you use insertvalue to create a struct or array of the two 64-bit ints, finally a single return that returns the struct/array.

The backend may express using very few instructions on target CPUs. Or it may require more.